# error log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (pdflatex). log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, miktex

Facing problems with rmarkdown in Rstudio environment.

The following error is being reported:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (pdflatex).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
```

need help.

I saw the same problem being reported by few others but did not find a proposed way to solve.

```
MikTex 2.9.5721 x64
pandoc 1.15.0.6
```

> sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.1.1        Rcpp_0.12.0     curl_0.9.3      digest_0.6.8             git2r_0.11.0    htmltools_0.2.6 httr_1.0.0      magrittr_1.5   
[9] memoise_0.2.1   rmarkdown_0.8   rversions_1.0.2 stringi_0.5-5      stringr_1.0.0   tools_3.1.2     xml2_0.1.1      yaml_2.1.13
```